# Python 3.9 virtual environments with windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python-venv, python-3.9

I faced this silly problem since the last 2 days, and it turns me mad.

Since I installed python 3.9 on my new Windows 10 machine, when I run the command `python3 -m venv .\venv`, I get the error "**Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.**"

If I switch off the app execution aliases, as mentioned in the message, I got a message:
**'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

So, I looked at similar issues on Stackoverflow and fixed the path in the environment variables (in the user variables and in the system variables).

I added to the variable 'paths' the 2 following entries:

> C:\Users{myuser}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
> C:\Users{myuser}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\

In all cases seen on Stack, that should have been enough. Not in my case.
I rebooted my machine twice, to make sure the new variables were picked up, but it's still the same.

I must add that I am using daily my Jupyter Lab environment, and everything works fine.
It's just this venv that refuses to work.

Does anyone has a hint on other places I should look for ?

Comment: Try python instead of python3.

Comment: I forgot to mention this: if I replace python3 with python, it 'thinks' for a couple of seconds, and then give me back the command line. It seems to create some structures, with an include, lib and scripts subfolder, but none of them contains a 'source' item.

Comment: have you tried `virtualenv venv`. And when you type PATH in the command line do the python folders show up? Lastly, are you running jupyter lab from anaconda or from a standalone pip install?

Comment: It's ok. I tried this, but it stopped there, and I was not able to activate the environment, as the ````source``` command was missing. I looked in Stack on activation with Windows, and I found the ````activate```` one in the scripts  folder and ran it. It's ok now.

Comment: ````virtualenv venv```` works really fine. I use Jupyter lab daily. It's on a standalone pip install, with python, pandas, sk-learn and torch. All this is working fine, but I am now looking at webapps to give access to my tools. This is a new domain for me, and I am self training on RealPython. If you can recommend any additional / alternative resource(s), they will be warmly welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

Solution found thanks to [Michael Vine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9319482/michael-vine).
To summarize:

- referring to python instead of python3 in the command line
- using [virtualenv venv] instead of [python -m venv .\venv] as I did